# Cannot delete an email message using POP3

Tags: c#, pop3

I have code that uses POP3 to access an email account and search for messages that were sent but the address did not exist. After processing them, I delete the failure message. I have one client who can get and process the messages, but is not able to delete them. They keep getting the message `Error deleting message 1: -ERR The specified message is out of range.`

The code for my delete method is below. This works for most clients, and is pretty simple, so I'm not sure why it isn't working.

```
    public bool Delete(int index)
    {
        bool result = false;
        String response = SendReceive("DELE ", index.ToString());
        if (response.StartsWith("+OK"))
            result = true;
        else
            logger.Log("Error deleting message " + index + ": " + response, Verbose.LogImportant);

        return result;
    }
```

For the SendReceive method:

```
    private String SendReceive(String command, String parameter)
    {
        String result = null;
        try
        {
            String myCommand = command.ToUpper().Trim() + " " + parameter.Trim() + Environment.NewLine;
            byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myCommand.ToCharArray());
            tcpClient.GetStream().Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            result = streamReader.ReadLine();
        }
        catch { }   //  Not logged in...
        return result;
    }
```

The index is taken directly from the received email, and the connection is not closed until after the delete method has processed. Since there has to be an email returned to run this method, and since the index runs from 1 to n, with a 1 being sent, I don't see what is causing this to fail.

Answer (score 1):

The `SendReceive()` call looks wrong. My guess is that it should probably have a `{0}` in the format string. In other words, your code is probably sending `DELE` instead of `DELE 1`.

Comment: Thank you @jstedfast for the response. It was an oversight on my part to not include my SendReceive method.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't fix it. I was already sending the correct information. I just hadn't included the code to show that, so I updated my question.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't already sent a DELE 1 command before this? You can't DELE the same message more than once.

Comment: Does it work if you use a library like [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit)? If so, I recommend taking the time to add logging to your code. Take it from me, it will be an invaluable investment of your time.